# mysql 勤務データ 日付またぎのID抽出

Tags: mysql

以下のデータが用意されています。

```
USER_NAME,ID,START_TIME,END_TIME
AAAA,1,2017/8/9 9:00,2017/8/9 18:00
AAAA,5,2017/8/9 12:00,2017/8/9 13:00
BBBB,2,2017/8/9 22:00,2017/8/10 00:00
BBBB,2,2017/8/10 00:00,2017/8/10 07:00
BBBB,5,2017/8/10 03:00,2017/8/10 04:00
```

※START_TIME,END_TIMEはDATETIME型です。
ID [1]は勤務時間。[5]は1時間休憩です。

この時間を15分ごとに区切りその時間はどのIDが該当するか表示させる必要があります。
USER_NAMEがAAAAさんのデータは15分ごとにID取得ができましたが、BBBBさんの[BBBB,2,2017/8/9 22:00,2017/8/10 00:00]このようにEND_TIMEの日付が翌日になるとIDがうまく抽出できませんでした。

以下の書き方だと時間のみ抽出する形のため、抽出されないのだと思いますが、具体的にどう書き換えれば日付が翌日になった場合でもIDがうまく抽出できるのでしょうか。

```
SELECT distinct
       USER_NAME,
       ID,
       case when (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') > '00:00' and (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(START_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') <'00:15')) then SCHEDULE_INTERVAL_TYPE_ID end as '00:00',
            case when (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') > '00:15' and (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(START_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') <'00:30')) then SCHEDULE_INTERVAL_TYPE_ID end as '00:15',
.
.
.
. 15分ごとに時刻を変更して23:59まで続きます。
case when (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') > '23:30' and (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(START_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') <'23:45')) then SCHEDULE_INTERVAL_TYPE_ID end as '23:30',
            case when (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') > '23:45' and (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(START_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') <'23:59')) then SCHEDULE_INTERVAL_TYPE_ID end as '23:45'
FROM テーブル1
WHERE 
    DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(START_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%Y%m%d') = DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%Y%m%d');
```

Answer (score 1):

同一USER_NAMEで午前0時をまたぐ場合、前日の23:59までのレコードと翌日の00:00以降のレコードを別々に登録しているように見えたので、それであれば、`END_TIME`の時刻が`00:00`と一致する場合を各列の条件に追加すればよいと思います。(以下、例)

```
case when (
    (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') > '00:00'
     OR
     DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') = '00:00'
     )
     and
     DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(START_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') <'00:15')
     ) then SCHEDULE_INTERVAL_TYPE_ID end as '00:00',
/* 途中省略 */
case when (
    (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') > '23:45'
     OR
     DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') = '00:00'
    )
    and
    DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(START_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') < '23:59')
    ) then SCHEDULE_INTERVAL_TYPE_ID end as '23:45'
```

＃1レコードで`START_TIME`と`END_TIME`が日をまたぐ場合は、`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`関数で通算秒数に直して差を見る必要があると考えましたが、質問例から、その必要はないと思いましたので、簡易な方法を回答しました。

Comment: 返答遅れましたが、求めていたものが表示されるようになりました。本当にありがとうございます！

Comment: @akichan 解決した場合はお礼をコメントに残すのではなく参考になった回答を承認してください。