# mysql 最大値の抽出と並び替え

Tags: mysql, sql

一度、こちらで回答いただいた内容なのですが追加で質問させていただきます。
[mysql 勤務データ 日付またぎのID抽出](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37076/mysql-%E5%8B%A4%E5%8B%99%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF-%E6%97%A5%E4%BB%98%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8E%E3%81%AEid%E6%8A%BD%E5%87%BA)

以下のように15分ごとにIDが表示されるようになりました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

①この15分ごとに表示されたIDを以下のようにUSER_NAMEごとにまとめたい。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

②USER_NAMEごとにまとめた後にSTART_TIME順に並び替えたい。

①についてはエクセルのPIVOTなどで値を最大値にすれば表示させることもできますが、SQL上で最大のIDを表示させたい。
②についてはMIN(START_TIME)と入れてもうまくでてきません。（1行のみのデータが表示されてしまう）
①②をSQL上で表示させることは可能なのでしょうか。。

```
元データ
SELECT distinct
        県コード,
        市コード,
       USER_NAME,
       ID,
       case when (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') > '00:00' and (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(START_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') <'00:15')) then SCHEDULE_INTERVAL_TYPE_ID end as '00:00',
            case when (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') > '00:15' and (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(START_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') <'00:30')) then SCHEDULE_INTERVAL_TYPE_ID end as '00:15',
case when (
    (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') > '00:00'
     OR
     DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') = '00:00'
     )
     and
     DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(START_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') <'00:15')
     ) then SCHEDULE_INTERVAL_TYPE_ID end as '00:00',
/* 途中省略 */
case when (
    (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') > '23:45'
     OR
     DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') = '00:00'
    )
    and
    DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(START_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%H:%i') < '23:59')
    ) then SCHEDULE_INTERVAL_TYPE_ID end as '23:45'
FROM テーブル1
WHERE 
    DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(START_TIME, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%Y%m%d') = DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '+00:00','Asia/Tokyo') ,'%Y%m%d');
```

Answer (score 1):

＃コメントの内容は異なる質問と見受けましたので、別回答として書きます。

前述のコメントで質問されているのは、時間帯(15分別)に最大値であるIDの件数を取得する(ユーザ別の結果をまとめる)、ということと想定しました。こういうSQL文でしょうか?

```
    /* イメージ */
    (
    WITH tbl as (先の回答のSELECT文全体)
    select '00:00' as "time", "t00:00" as "id", count("t00:00") from tbl where "t00:00" is not null group by "id"
    union
    select '00:15' as "time", "t00:15" as "id", count("t00:15") from tbl where "t00:15" is not null group by "id"
    union
    /* 途中省略 */
    union
    select '23:45' as "time", "t23:45" as "id", count("t23:45") from tbl where "t23:45" is not null group by "id"
    ) order by "time","id";

    /* 取得イメージ */
     time  | id | count
    -------+----+-------
     /* 途中省略 */
     10:30 |  1 |     2
     10:30 |  3 |     1
     10:45 |  1 |     2
     10:45 |  3 |     1
     11:00 |  1 |     1
     11:00 |  3 |     1
     /* 以後省略 */
```

＃時間帯情報が列名に変換されていてSELECTの条件に書けないため、`UNION`使って時間帯別に`count(時間帯)`として取得する方法を採っています。個人的には見通しの悪いSQL文と思うので、元のテーブルの構造を見直して、取得しやすくすることをお勧めします。

## 追記

WITH句を使えない場合、「`(先の回答のSELECT文全体)`」を(例えば`tbl`という名前の)VIEWとして定義し`SELECT`で参照する(例えば`select ～ from tbl where "t00:00" is not null`)か、
`select ～ from tbl`の`tbl`の箇所に直接「`(先の回答のSELECT文全体)`」を記述する方法(例えば`select ～ from (先の回答のSELECT文全体) t`)をとることになると思います。

```
    /* 直接記述するイメージ */
    select '00:00' as "time", "t00:00" as "id",count("t00:00") from (先の回答のSELECT文全体) tbl where "t00:00" is not null group by id
    union
    select '00:15' as "time", "t00:15" as "id",count("t00:15") from (先の回答のSELECT文全体) tbl where "t00:15" is not null group by id
    union
    /* 途中省略 */
    union
    select '23:45' as "time", "t23:45" as "id",count("t23:45") from (先の回答のSELECT文全体) tbl where "t23:45" is not null group by id
    ;
```

＃MySQLだと、VIEWではなく`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`で一時テーブルを作成する方法もあるようですが、これだと`UNION`や`JOIN`ができないので、私のアイディアには適用できないようです。

Comment: 何度もありがとうございます。mysqlではWITHに対応していない？のかWITHと同じ機能をもったものはないでしょうか？

Comment: MySQLで`WITH`句が使えるのは8.0かららしいですね。失礼しました。`WITH`句を使ったのは`UNION`で記述する`SELECT`文に同じ一時テーブルを与えたかったからなので、追記したようにVIEWを作るか、(長くなるのを覚悟で)SELECT文の`FROM`のところに直接サブクエリを書けば同じ結果になると思います。

Comment: 頭が悪く申し訳ありませんが、＞(長くなるのを覚悟で)SELECT文‌​のFROMのところに直接サブクエリを書け‌​ば同じ結果になると思います。→この箇所をもう少し具体的に教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 直接記述する場合のイメージを回答に追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！しかしながら、だいぶ長くなってしまいますね。。例えば、(先の回答のSELECT文全体)を変数？のように名前をつけて短くすることは可能なのでしょうか。こちらの環境の問題ですが、VIEWもつかえなかったため、苦戦しています。

Comment: サブクエリ(この場合「(先の回答のSELECT文全体)」)を変数的に扱うための標準SQL的解法がWITH句と認識していますので、なければVIEWを定義する、という案でした。どちらも無理であるなら、この辺が限界と考えます。この質問を一度クローズして、「このDBに対しできること」を示して別途質問すると、他の回答が得られるかも知れません。

Answer (score -1):

＃性能は度外視します。

①は、質問にあるselect文の結果を一時表にして、各カラム(「00:00」から「23:45」まで)について、最大値を取得すればよいかと思います。

```
    /* イメージ */
    select user_name,max("00:00"),max("00:15"),/* 途中略 */,max("23:45")
    from ( 質問のselect文全体 ) t
    group by t.user_name;
```

②は、質問の意図がわからないので回答は控えます。(質問にあるselect文では`START_TIME`は取得していないので、並び替える、の意図が不明でした)

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速、①の「max("00:00"),max("00:15")」とやってみたところ、IDの数値ではなく「00:00」「00:15」「00:30」といった時刻が返ってくるようです。IDの最大値をuser_name、15分ごとに出すには違う書き方になるのでしょうか。

Comment: 「質問のselect文全体」で定義しているカラム名を指定する、の意味でした。ダブルクオートで囲むと文字定数になるのですね。失礼しました。mysqlでカラム名を指定する記法で試してみて下さい。(シングルクオートでしょうか)

Comment: 数値のみではうまくでてこず、カラム名を「't0000'」のようにすればうまく抽出できました。ありがとうございます！最大値で出したものをさらにID、時間別に出そうとし、select user_name,count("t00:00"),count("t00:15"),/* 途中略 */,count("t23:45")
    from ( select user_name,max("00:00"),max("00:15"),/* 途中略 */,max("23:45")
    from ( 質問のselect文全体 ) t
    group by t.user_name ) r group by ID;としてみましたが、今後は時間ごとの数字が全て同じになってしまいます。カラムを集計するにはmaxとはまた別の方法になるのでしょうか？